# WebScraping & web navigation simulation

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm make a webscraper and I already know how to scrap some data and convert them to Json with this code I made :

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var app     = express();
var url = 'http://www.footmercato.net/';

request(url, function(err, resp, body) {
     if (!err) {
       var $ = cheerio.load(body);
       var data = [];
       var i = 1;
       $('.text').each(function(i, element) {
         var article = $('p');
         var jsObject = { title : "", article : "", date : "" };
         var articleTxt = article.text();
         jsObject.article = articleTxt;
         data.push(jsObject);
       })
       var json = JSON.stringify(data);
       fs.writeFile('output.json', JSON.stringify(json, null, 4), function(err) {
           console.log('File successfully written!');
       })
   }
 });

  app.listen('8080');
```

But I would like to navigate to the website I'm scraping, fill out form and going to others pages.

Does somebody know if i can do it with cheerio or how I can add it to my existing code ?

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you have a look at phantomjs or casperjs

Comment: Ok thank you Erik, I'm going to have a look on them but I'm looking a way to associate phamtomJs or casperJS (which is the best ?) to my cheerio code...

Comment: which is best? well, casper is an extra layer between your application logic and phantom, there is no "better", you decide what level you like to code in. I never used casper, I assume it's more user friendly. How to use cherio with phantom? much like you use `request` in your example. You can setup child processes and parse output, but it's way to much for me to explain here. I used cherio and phantom in a project, but then I did not need to control the webpage as you explain you need to do by filling and sending forms. That logic you have to solve in phantom

Comment: if you did not already know, it's worth mentioning that phantomjs is not a nodejs module.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [webdriverio](http://webdriver.io/guide.html) actually he will open a browser window, and then you can manipulate the dom through the [`webdriverio` api](http://webdriver.io/api.html) to handle forms mouse clicks, and navigate from one page to an other.

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var options = {
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'firefox'
    }
};
webdriverio
    .remote(options)
    .init()
    .url('http://www.google.com')
    .getTitle().then(function(title) {
        console.log('Title was: ' + title);
    })
    .end();
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot Alexandru, it looks like very powerfull and perfoect for what I need. I'm going to try it !